# Recording multiple pixels simultaneously in CMOS or CCD image sensors

Tags: cmos, image-sensor, ccd

Is it possible to recording multiple pixels simultaneously in CMOS or CCD image sensors?
Because of the low intensity of radiation I need to increase the surface area of the each pixel (photodetector).
Is it possible that data of 4 or 16 pixels will be measured at the same time and sum together?
For example, a 1024 * 1024 pixel image sensor with 10 * 10 micron pixel area is worked similar to a 512 * 512 pixel image sensor with 20 * 20 micron pixel area.

Comment: Look for "pixel binning"
depending on the sensor, this could be done on the sensor itself. Have a look on your sensor datasheet.

Comment: This is very easy to do with math.  Just have your program add the values of every 4 cells.   It's actually not a new idea you have, it's commonplace. You trade resolution for sensitivity.

Comment: If you're really trying to measure something "low intensity" BTW, note that CCD's are (generally) superior to CMOS sensors.  If you cool the sensor (i.e. with a peltier) you can greatly reduce the random noise.  Astronomical CCD's in professional telescopes are cooled with liquid nitrogen!   Also - Look at Hamamatsu for your parts.  They are more expensive but they are THE BEST.

Comment: There’s no free lunches to be had in the manner you desire.  A pixel is a pixel, and only so much light per unit area will fall upon it.  Reading multiple pixels simultaneously will simply yield the total area of the multiple pixels divided by the number of pixels, each pixel stands alone. Pixel binning might help a little, otherwise you’re up against physics. Characterising your sensor and its various noise sources at various temperatures and subtracting that from your signal, and keeping it cool as possible, all help to increase SNR.